# How to Set an Ellipse in a random Angle and Direction in a Canvas with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi im am new in C# WPF and im looking to set an Ellipse in any angle and direction. Unfortunately i have not found a solution for this. My simple solution does not take to account the angles that im calculating.
Im using the Canvas.setTop, Canvas.setRight... etc to set this angle, but i would like to set this with my calculated angle.

Here is my XAMLcode:

```
<Window x:Class="someApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:someApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Background="LightBlue"
        Title="app" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Name="enviroinment" Background="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="297" Margin="120,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="639">
            <Button Content="Start/Stop" Canvas.Left="-97" Canvas.Top="24" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is my main Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace someApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Ellipse> People = new List<Ellipse>();
        double SPEED = 1.5;
        double _angle = 90;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.05);
            timer.Tick += movePeople;
            timer.IsEnabled = true;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void createPeople()
        {
            for(int i= 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Ellipse person = new Ellipse();
                person.Width = 10;
                person.Height = 10;
                person.Fill = Brushes.Gray;
                //Canvas.SetLeft(person, rand.Next(0, (int)environment.ActualWidth));
                //Canvas.SetTop(person, rand.Next(0,(int)environment.ActualHeight));
                People.Add(person);
            }
        }

        private void setDirection()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < People.Count; i++)
            {
                _angle = rand.Next(0, 90);
                SPEED = 0.5 + rand.NextDouble();
                double radians = Math.PI * _angle / 180.0;

                double initPosX = rand.Next(0, (int)environment.ActualWidth);
                double initPosY = rand.Next(0, (int)environment.ActualHeight);

                double x = initPosX + Math.Sin(radians) * SPEED;
                double y = initPosY +  Math.Cos(radians) * SPEED;
               
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(People[i], x);
                    Canvas.SetTop(People[i], y);
                }
                if(i == 1)
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(People[i], x);
                    Canvas.SetBottom(People[i], y);
                }
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    Canvas.SetRight(People[i], x);
                    Canvas.SetTop(People[i], y);
                }
                if (i == 3)
                {
                    Canvas.SetRight(People[i], x);
                    Canvas.SetBottom(People[i], y);
                }
                environment.Children.Add(People[i]);
            }
        }

        private void movePeople(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < People.Count; i++)
            {
                
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    double x = Canvas.GetLeft(People[i]);
                    double y = Canvas.GetTop(People[i]);

                    x += SPEED;
                    y += SPEED;

                    Canvas.SetLeft(People[i], x);
                    Canvas.SetTop(People[i], y);
                }
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    double x = Canvas.GetLeft(People[i]);
                    double y = Canvas.GetBottom(People[i]);

                    x += SPEED;
                    y += SPEED;

                    Canvas.SetLeft(People[i], x);
                    Canvas.SetBottom(People[i], y);
                }
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    double x = Canvas.GetRight(People[i]);
                    double y = Canvas.GetTop(People[i]);

                    x += SPEED;
                    y += SPEED;

                    Canvas.SetRight(People[i], x);
                    Canvas.SetTop(People[i], y);
                }
                if (i == 3)
                {
                    double x = Canvas.GetRight(People[i]);
                    double y = Canvas.GetBottom(People[i]);

                    x += SPEED;
                    y += SPEED;

                    Canvas.SetRight(People[i], x);
                    Canvas.SetBottom(People[i], y);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (timer.IsEnabled)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                People.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                createPeople();
                setDirection();
                timer.Start();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Please provide a clear description of what you are trying to do. What is the purpose of that angle? What is the overall idea behind your code? There are four Ellipses placed at random positions, that you seemingly want to move cyclically. But what exactly does "*set an Ellipse in any angle and direction*" mean?

Comment: What i want to do is a Simulation of People moving in a rectangle. This are referenced as ellipses that moves in any random direction at start. My code only goes at 45 degrees in 4 different directions. This is very limited, i need to move my Ellipse to 20, 10 or other degrees.

Comment: And you certainly need to move every Person in a different direction, not all in the same, right?

Comment: yes please it is like this simulation :(directions change only after collision )  https://www.washingtonpost.com/gdpr-consent/?next_url=https%3a%2f%2fwww.washingtonpost.com%2fgraphics%2f2020%2fworld%2fcorona-simulator%2f

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should do it right from the beginning and write an application that implements the MVVM architectural pattern.

There would be a class that models the moving object with a position and a velocity. The class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and its properties fire the PropertyChanged event when their value changes.

```
public class Particle : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Point position;
    public Point Position
    {
        get { return position; }
        set
        {
            position = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Position));
        }
    }

    private Vector velocity;
    public Vector Velocity
    {
        get { return velocity; }
        set
        {
            velocity = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Velocity));
        }
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The main view model class would hold a collection of Particles in an ObservableCollection property and implement their motion behaviour, given by `s = v * dt`.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Particle> Particles { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Particle>();

    private DateTime lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;

    public void MoveParticles()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var dt = (now - lastUpdate).TotalSeconds;

        foreach (var particle in Particles)
        {
            particle.Position += particle.Velocity * dt;
        }

        lastUpdate = now;
    }
}
```

To visualize those Particles, you would use an ItemsControl with a Canvas as ItemsPanel. Its ItemContainerStyle would take care for setting the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties according to the Particle Position, and the ItemTemplate would define the visual appearance:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Particles}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Position.X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Position.Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Fill="Red">
                <Path.Data>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

To glue the view and the view model together, assign an instance of the ViewModel class to the DataContext of the view. Start a timer to cyclically update the view model, which would automatically also update the view.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = vm;

    vm.Particles.Add(new Particle
    {
        Position = new Point(200, 100),
        Velocity = new Vector(10, 10)
    });

    vm.Particles.Add(new Particle
    {
        Position = new Point(200, 200),
        Velocity = new Vector(10, -10)
    });

    var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50) };

    timer.Tick += (s, e) => vm.MoveParticles();
    timer.Start();
}
```

---

An optional collision detection would now be implemented in the view model class. It would simply change the Velocity vectors of those Particles that are nearer than a predefined minimal distance, where the distance of two Particles is

```
var distance = (particle1.Position - particle2.Position).Length;
```